# Gravity Forms/CiviCRM add on - adding record to groups

Tags: groups, forms, integration, plugin

I am using the Gravity forms to CiviCRM plugin. http://shop.civivip.com/civi-plugins/gravity-forms-integration/

It is passing the data but not seeing where it actually will specify what group you want data to send to. Just has Groups but can't select which one.
[image: Gravity Form feed]

Have others successfully sent gravity form data into CiviCRM groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you tell me what version you are running? We added support for groups and tags in our latest version. On the contact feed it looks like this.
[image: Groups and Tags]
If you're wanting to add to different groups based on their selection then you would create one feed per group and make the feed conditional based on that criteria.

Comment: Yeah, that looks a lot better. Using Gravity Forms/CiviCRM Plugin ver 1.0.7. CiviCRM ver 4.7.23.

Comment: Look for an update button in your plugins list. Version 1.0.8 has groups and tags changes illustrated above.